# Immutables custom create and of methods

Tags: java, reflection, immutability, immutables-library

I am changing a library that uses  [Immutables](https://immutables.github.io/).
In the class that I change I just added a new variable and in the generated classes I see different signatures in the `create` and `of` methods.

```
ImmutableMyClass.of(previous variables ...,  int varNew)

ModifiableMyClass.create(previous variables ...,  int varNew)
```

Since there are users of this library that call the previous versions of these methods I need to keep previous versions while providing the new versions for a new feature; otherwise, apparently, I am breaking the backward compatibility.

How do I have `Immutables` create custom `create` and `of` methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add the missing methods yourself as defined in library documentation here : https://immutables.github.io/immutable.html#expressive-factory-methods. So for the missing methods you define `public static MyClass of(...)` and `public static MyClass create(...)` methods as below

```
@Value.Modifiable
@Value.Immutable
public abstract class Point {
  @Value.Parameter
  public abstract double x();
  @Value.Parameter
  public abstract double y();
  //You added this for example
  @Value.Parameter
  public abstract double z();

  public static Point origin() {
    return ImmutablePoint.of(0, 0);
  }

  public static MyClass of(double x, double y) {
    return ImmutableMyClass.of(x, y, 0); // or another implementation you need
    
  }

   public static MyClass create(double x, double y) {
    return ModifiableMyClass.create(x, y, 0); // or another implementation you need
  }
}
```